# Error while trying to get json with jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery, imdb

I'm trying to crate a code that will get some info about a movie using some IMDB API, but I'm getting two errors that I can't fix...

This is the code:

```
<body>
    <h1>The bourne Legacy</h1>
    <h2>2012</h2>

    <script>
        (function() {

            function getMovieInfo( title, year ) {

                $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url: "http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: { 'q': title, 'year': year },
                    success: function(info) {
                        console.log(info.year);
                    }
                });
            }

            getMovieInfo( $('h1').text(), $('h2').text() );

        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

and the errors are the next:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?callback=jQuery18108839007553178817_1347625688866&q=The+bourne+Legacy&year=2012&_=1347625688869". jquery.min.js:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : www.deanclatworthy.com:1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function getMovieInfo( title, year ) {

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url: "http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'q': title, 'year': year },
            success: function(info) {
                console.log(info.year);
            }
        });
    }

    getMovieInfo( $('h1').text(), $('h2').text() );

});
```

Comment: Doesn't work... still the same error, and i edited the code above